# Automatically provisioning remote host with debugging tools: VS 2013

Tags: remote-debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am working on starting a driver development project and I want to do debugging on a remote target.  I am using VMware for both sessions and they are both running on the same physical laptop.

Host: VMware session: Win8 Pro x64, latest version of VS 2013 RC, WDK 8.1.
Target: VMware session: Win8 Pro x86.

On the target, I have:

- enabled the Administrator account.
- enabled file/printer sharing and network discovery.

I can ping each VM from the other.  And I have disabled the Windows firewall on both machines.

When I go to Driver/Test/Configure Computers... I enter the name of the computer I want to debug and hit Next.  I select "Provision computer and automatically configure debuggers" and hit Next.  It spins for a while and then I get this failure:

Initialize: Computer: 
[21:20:05:374]: Account restrictions are preventing this user from signing in. For example: blank passwords aren't allowed, sign-in times are limited, or a policy restriction has been enforced
Progress event: Current: 0, Max: -1, Message: "Account restrictions are preventing this user from signing in. For example: blank passwords aren't allowed, sign-in times are limited, or a policy restriction has been enforced"
Progress event: Current: 0, Max: -1, Message: "Computer configuration log file://C:/Users/Kent/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/DriverTest/Install/Driver%20Test%20Computer%20Configuration%2020131027212000868.log"

The Administrator account on the target machine is blank and there are no AD policies applied to it.  This message is fairly useless otherwise.  I'm going to manually install and configure the WDK debuggers.

Does anyone have any pointers about how to get the automatic provisioning working?

Comment: Do you have the same admin account and non-blank password on both installations?

Comment: The Admin accounts on both machines have been activated and the password on both accounts is blank.  The machines are on the same workgroup but not logged in to any domain.

Comment: Your error message above states: `blank passwords aren't allowed`

Comment: Perhaps I misread that.  I was reading that whole message as "Account restrictions (such as 'blank passwords aren't allowed') are preventing..."  Since blank passwords *are* allowed on both my systems, I thought that did not apply in this case.  I will try it with non-blank passwords and see what happens.

Comment: Ugh!  Turned off "no password" option and VS is now contacting my target machine.  But neither of these machines is on a domain and it is refusing to authenticate.  I keep trying <hostMachineName>\administrator and it refuses to connect.  I've also tried workgroup\administrator.  Nothing works so far.  Mark, you gave the correct answer to my original question.  Post it as an answer FTW.

Comment: Ran "WDK Test Target Setup" on the target machine and it finally configured the device.  There were 2 errors configuring debuggers.  Still working through that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indicated you had a blank password, and the error message stated:

> Initialize: Computer: [21:20:05:374]: Account restrictions are preventing this user from signing in. For example: **blank passwords aren't allowed**...

If neither is on a domain, I've had luck with just the same username/password on both machines, but lately at work I've only been using native C++ with authentication disabled so it's never been a problem.

Comment: You say you've only been using native C++ with auth disabled.  Can you elaborate on that a bit?  I was trying to set this up for C++ driver development, but I still had all the problems setting up the debuggers.  When I execute a remote debugging session, it always logs in with WDKRemoteUser.  How are you using "auth disabled"?

Comment: @Kent, Set the native C++ project property under Debugging, Connection to "Remote with no authentication".  Then run msvsmon.exe on the remote system.  Under Tools, Options set to "No Authentication" and check "Allow any user to debug".  Disclaimer, I'm using VS2012 but I expect it hasn't changed in VS2013.  This is for user applications as well.  For drivers I've been using WinDbg with over 1394 for remoting.